# ElasticSearch/Painless: How do I access/sum all values in an object

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-painless

I've been looking at aggregations, and at scripting using `painless`, and I am not able to figure out how to iterate/sum over all values in an object.

Example:

My mapping looks like

```
"field1": {
  "properties": {
    "subfield1": {
      "type": "float"
    },
    "subfield2": {
      "type": "float"
    },
    "subfield3": {
      "type": "float"
    }
  }
}
```

Let's assume my data looks like this:

```
{
  "field1" : {
    "subfield1": 50.0,
    "subfield2": 20.5,
    "subfield3": 30.5
  }
}
```

I want to perform a range query on `50.0 + 20.5 + 30.5`, or, basically, access all the values within the `field1` object in some way.

Aggregations do not allow me to use wild-cards in fields.
I was [looking at the code for `LeafDocLookup`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/search/lookup/LeafDocLookup.java#L149) (used internally for painless), and I see that the relevant methods are disabled.

I've managed to write the script like this:

```
"query": {
  "script": {
    "script": {
      "inline": "return (doc['field1.subfield1'].value + doc['field1.subfield2'].value + doc['field1.subfield3'].value > 50);",
      "lang": "painless"
    }
  }
}
```

but this is obviously sub-optimal, and doesn't solve the main issue of dynamic keys.

Comment: Can you store the total (i.e. sum) of the sub-keys when you create or update the document? Then you just have one field to query against and don't have to worry about the dynamic keys names.

Comment: I can, but I'm sure there are more use-cases where I need to access all elements of a hashmap. Isn't that exactly why we have methods like `keySet()` and `values()`?

Comment: Painless likely supports getting all subobjects of a field, but in general I would recommend not using scripts in ES queries. They are slow and usually there is a better way to query or to store the documents to avoid scripts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally figured it out! It isn't available in the `doc` object within elasticsearch, but it *is* available within `_ctx.source`.

So, I can access the object as a Java `HashMap` object if I use `params['_source']`

```
"query": {
  "script": {
    "script": {
      "inline": "float sum = 0.0f; for (float v: params['_source'].values()) { sum += v; } return (sum > 50);",
      "lang": "painless"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice one, +1. I am using this to find all attributes that have more than a given number of array entries, as in `"params['_source'].keySet().size() > 990"`