# Elastic search aggregation on map - on each key

Tags: elasticsearch

I have following kind of documents.

document 1

```
{
  "doc": {
    "id": 1,
    "errors": {
      "e1":5,
      "e2":20,
      "e3":30
    },
    "warnings": {
      "w1":1,
      "w2":2
    }
  }
}
```

document 2

```
{
  "doc": {
    "id": 2,
    "errors": {
      "e1":10
    },
    "warnings": {
      "w1":1,
      "w2":2,
      "w3":33,
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to get following sum stats in one or more calls. Is it possible? I tried various solution but all works when *key* is known. In my case map *keys*  (e1, e2 etc) are not known.

```
{
  "errors": {
    "e1": 15,
    "e2": 20,
    "e3": 30
  },
  "warnings": {
    "w1": 2,
    "w2": 4,
    "w3": 33
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two solutions, none of them are pretty. I have to point out that the option 2 should be the preferred way to go since option 1 uses an experimental feature.

## 1. Dynamic mapping, [experimental] scripted aggregation

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43901636/elasticsearch-painless-how-do-i-access-sum-all-values-in-an-object) and the [Scripted Metric Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html) page of ES docs, I began with just inserting your documents to non-existing index (which by default creates [dynamic mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-mapping.html)).

**NB**: I tested this on ES 5.4, but the documentation suggests that this feature is available from at least 2.0.

The resulting query for aggregation is the following:

```
POST /my_index/my_type/_search
{
    "size": 0,
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {}
    },
    "aggs": {
        "errors": {
            "scripted_metric": {
                "init_script" : "params._agg.errors = [:]",
                "map_script" : "for (t in params['_source']['doc']['errors'].entrySet()) { params._agg.errors[t.key] = t.value } ",
                "combine_script" : "return params._agg.errors",
                "reduce_script": "Map res = [:] ; for (a in params._aggs) { for (t in a.entrySet()) { res[t.key] = res.containsKey(t.key) ? res[t.key] + t.value : t.value } }  return res"

            }
        },
        "warnings": {
            "scripted_metric": {
                "init_script" : "params._agg.errors = [:]",
                "map_script" : "for (t in params['_source']['doc']['warnings'].entrySet()) { params._agg.errors[t.key] = t.value } ",
                "combine_script" : "return params._agg.errors",
                "reduce_script": "Map res = [:] ; for (a in params._aggs) { for (t in a.entrySet()) { res[t.key] = res.containsKey(t.key) ? res[t.key] + t.value : t.value } }  return res"

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which produces this output:

```
{
   ...
   "aggregations": {
      "warnings": {
         "value": {
            "w1": 2,
            "w2": 4,
            "w3": 33
         }
      },
      "errors": {
         "value": {
            "e1": 15,
            "e2": 20,
            "e3": 30
         }
      }
   }
}
```

If you are following this path you might be interested in the JavaDoc of what [`params['_source']`](http://xbib.org/elasticsearch/2.1.1/apidocs/org/elasticsearch/search/lookup/SourceLookup.html) is underneath.

**Warning**: I believe that scripted aggregation is not efficient and for better performance you should check out the option 2 or a different data processing engine.

What does [experimental](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html) mean:

> This functionality is experimental and may be changed or removed
> completely in a future release. Elastic will take a best effort
> approach to fix any issues, but experimental features are not subject
> to the support SLA of official GA features.

With this in mind we proceed to option 2.

## 2. Static nested mapping, nested aggregation

Here the idea is to store your data differently and essentially be able to query and aggregate it differently. Firstly, we need to create a mapping using [nested data type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html).

```
PUT /my_index_nested/
{
    "mappings": {
        "my_type": {
            "properties": {
                "errors": { 
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "name": {"type": "keyword"},
                        "val": {"type": "integer"}
                    }
                },
                "warnings": { 
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "name": {"type": "keyword"},
                        "val": {"type": "integer"}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A document in such an index will look like this:

```
     {
        "_index": "my_index_nested",
        "_type": "my_type",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "errors": [
              {
                 "name": "e1",
                 "val": 5
              },
              {
                 "name": "e2",
                 "val": 20
              },
              {
                 "name": "e3",
                 "val": 30
              }
           ],
           "warnings": [
              {
                 "name": "w1",
                 "val": 1
              },
              {
                 "name": "w2",
                 "val": 2
              }
           ]
        }
     }
```

Next we need to write the aggregate query. First we need to use [`nested aggregation`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html), which will allow us to query this special `nested` data type. But since we actually want to aggregate by `name`, and sum the values of `val`, we will need to do a [sub-aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html#_structuring_aggregations).

The resulting query is as follows (I am adding comments alongside the query for clarity):

```
POST /my_index_nested/my_type/_search
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "errors_top": {
            "nested": {
                // declare which nested objects we want to work with
                "path": "errors"  
            },
            "aggs": {
                "errors": {
                    // what we are aggregating - different values of name
                    "terms": {"field": "errors.name"}, 
                    // sub aggregation
                    "aggs": { 
                        "error_sum": {
                            // sum all val for same name
                            "sum": {"field": "errors.val"} 
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "warnings_top": {
            // analogous to errors
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this query will be like:

```
{
   ...
   "aggregations": {
      "errors_top": {
         "doc_count": 4,
         "errors": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
               {
                  "key": "e1",
                  "doc_count": 2,
                  "error_sum": {
                     "value": 15
                  }
               },
               {
                  "key": "e2",
                  "doc_count": 1,
                  "error_sum": {
                     "value": 20
                  }
               },
               {
                  "key": "e3",
                  "doc_count": 1,
                  "error_sum": {
                     "value": 30
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      "warnings_top": {
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the details examples and options. Since I am building new model, I have luxury of changing Map into named key value pair as per second option above. I will try that.